# what is Max number of pthreads in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, pthreads

If I can know the max number of pthreads to create in current activity, I can limit active threads.

I am using thread for load data from url and than process it to generate drawing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "max number of threads", or at least it's not that well-specified. The implementation details, memory/processor in your device, etc. etc. all affect this, but it's not really easy to decide theoretically. If you really badly want to know, you must try it by creating as much threads as possible until crash, but you'd better not be pushing the limits of the device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But as developer it's good to know the iPhone capacity and as well limit. So,It will reduce our pain and mind-storming.I post question here because there are lot's possibility that someone might have tried it earlier.Like i found something very interesting in below url.                                                        http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2008/May/msg00076.html

Answer (score 2):

In ios 5: 64
(more is possible, with workarounds using different priorities on the threads,
You can reach up to (64*3)-1 threads,
If you want even more, jailbreaking for multiple processes )

on modest phone-CPUs anyway, I guess it's time to re-think your approach way before reaching these limits :p

Answer (score 1):

Don't use threads for network connections, you'll just have many threads not in a runnable state. The processing part will probably be CPU limited so there's little to be gained by creating so many threads. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your scenario completely).

Use `NSURLConnection` to download asynchronously instead and use `dispatch_async` to the global concurrent queue to do the processing. GCD will distribute your tasks on its thread pool better than you will.

Comment: :Thanks for reply. I have map-view application and i am downloading data from server whenever my map view region will change. After that i am  drawing custom poly-line and add that annotation in to my map view. I have used dispatch_async  for add annotation which should be on main thread. It's work fine but some time annotation no shown on map-view.